# Album art can't be seen in Music Application?

Tags: release-loki, music

Im using LOKI . The music app doesn't shows ALBUM ART like it was shown in the Main page. How to resolve this. Please help. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check the folder containing your albums to see if they include an album cover image.